# iOS system icons

Tags: ios, ios5

Is there a way to access iOS icons? Eg. some hidden folder in the SDK?
In Android, it is possible to access drawables straight from the code, and there is even a folder in the SDK. Is this possible on iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking for https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor